Locating custom projection specification in QGIS
Several years ago, I constructed a custom projection in QGIS that I can no longer see in the 'project properties' list of CRSs. However, I can still use the custom projection as part of a print layout as part of the same project.
What this means is that I can use the projection to generate maps for printing, but I cannot access or view its specifications/definition. It seems that the print composer is accessing details of the custom projection from a different location than the project's list of CRSs.
I'm using QGIS 3.22.13 under Windows 10.
How can I retrieve details of the custom projection given that are visible in a print layout?

Have you looked in Settings->Custom Projections... as well as the project properties? https://i.sstatic.net/O9w3v4H1.png
